# Existence of some extension

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X_{0}$ be a linear closed proper subspace of real normed space $X$. Show that for every linear and continuous functional $\phi_{0}: X_0 \to \mathbb{R}  $ with norm 1 there exist a linear and continuous functional $\phi: X \to \mathbb{R} $ with norm 2 such that $\phi_{|{X_0}} = \phi_0$. 

I tried to use $\psi : span\{a, X_0\} \to \mathbb{R}$, for some $a \in X \setminus X_0$ such that $\psi(ta + x) = t + \phi_0(x), x \in X_0$ and then use Hahn-Banach, but I'm not sure how to prove that $\|\psi\| = 2$ (If this is the case).

Comment: Not sure if you can use Hahn-Banach, since in HB extended functional and the original functional should have the same norm. I could be mistaken.

Comment: @AnlamK I think he means to show that the functional psi has norm 2 and then use hahn banach to extend it to the whole space, which should work out imho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\psi_r(ta+x)=rt + \phi_0(x)$ instead. Then check that $r\mapsto \|\psi_r\|$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and apply the intermediate value theorem to find some $r>0$ with $\|\psi_r\|=2$ and extend by Hahn-Banach.